# Undefined Variable Name for Class Variable

Tags: python, function, class, undefined

Undefined Variable Name seems to be a common problem and I've followed the exact process as some of the examples on here, but I have not had any success.

From what I understand, you have to make a class if you have multiple functions, and then make an instance of the class to call these methods.

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
start = KMP()
start.read()


class KMP:

     def read(self):
         Text = "AGABBBACC"
         Pattern = "BBB"
         result = self.kmp(self, Pattern, Text)

     def kmp(self, Pattern, Text):
         ........
         ........
         return self.numOcc`
```

I'm getting a undefined name 'KMP', and I really don't understand why. Could anyone help me in solving this error?

Comment: What line does this error occur on?

Comment: @AlexanderRD it appeared at the very start of the code, `start = KMP()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define something before you use it. In your case you're trying to create an instance of the class `KMP` before the code that defines `KMP`.

You need to move your first statement after the point in which you define the class.

```
class KMP:

     def read(self):
         Text = "AGABBBACC"
         Pattern = "BBB"
         result = self.kmp(self, Pattern, Text)

     def kmp(self, Pattern, Text):
         ........
         ........
         return self.numOcc`

start = KMP()
start.read()
```

Comment: Oh such a simple solution! I am used to Java-like implementation where we write main methods at the time of the code. Am I correct in adding my `self` statements? I know that I have to write `result = self.kmp..."` based on other answers but I'm unsure if I have to use them in the arguments as well. I've tried to research this but have not seen as exact answer.

Comment: If you prefer, you can define a `main` function at the top for your main logic, but you still need to add a call to `main` at the end of the script.